# how to exclude fridays on my countdown

Tags: java, android, countdown

thats my countdown code. I wonder how to exclude fridays or saturdays for examlpe, from my code. Thanks in advance.

```
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd");
                // Event Date
                Date futureDate = dateFormat.parse("2017-4-2");
                Date currentDate = new Date();
                if (!currentDate.after(futureDate)) {
                    long diff = futureDate.getTime()
                            - currentDate.getTime();
                    long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                    diff -= days * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                    long hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                    diff -= hours * (60 * 60 * 1000);
                    long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
                    diff -= minutes * (60 * 1000);
                    long seconds = diff / 1000;
```

rest of the code deleted.

Comment: Please provide full information

Answer (score 0):

Just see how many fridays or saturdays are there and subtract them from the countdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Plain java
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //The date that you want to check
    calendar.setTime(currentDate );
    //Filter Friday and Saturday
    if(!calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.FRIDAY
           && !calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY){
       //process the date
    }


    //Using Joda time
    LocalDate theDate= new LocalDate(2016, 11, 12); //12 Nov 2016
    int dayOfTheWeek = theDate.dayOfWeek().get();   //an integer, representing the  day of the week

    if ( !DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY== dayOfTheWeek 
              &&!DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY== dayOfTheWeek ) {

    }
```